# Launching Outlook with a prefilled Body with HTML Content

Tags: html, coldfusion, outlook

In ColdFusion, one can use  to send pre-filled bodies WITH HTML Content, but cannot launch Outlook.

With HTML's "mailto:", one can launch Outlook but cannot open pre-filled bodies WITH HTML Content. I know the "mailto:" function can pre-fill bodies with regular text only.

Is there a way to launch outlook with a pre-filled body WITH HTML content?

Comment: Why do you want to launch Outlook?  What are you trying to do?  If it is simply sending emails then have ColdFusion do that for you.  It can send HTML formatted emails as well and you fill the body with whatever content you wish.

Comment: I want to launch Outlook as a preview (and editing) those HTML formatted emails before it actually sends. But I'm guessing this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a comparable scenario. Coldfusion is serverside, and the HTML mailto link just triggers the browser default behaviour (which may be not to open outlook, but do something else).

Comment: Ok. Do you know of anyway to launch outlook with pre-filled HTML content in the body?

Comment: mailto doesn't allow HTML content. Only plain text =\